# Showing a hidden form (using this.Hide()) from another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've hidden a form Form1 and have shown a new form Form2 using the following code:

```
    form_Form2 f = new form_Form2();
    this.Hide();
    f.Show();
```

where this == Form1. How do I then make Form1 visible again from Form2? I do not want to create a new instance of Form1, I just want to make it show up again because the this.Hide() function keeps the data on the form instead of fully closing it.

Comment: Subscribe the FormClosing event to know that the form is about to close.  Or use ShowDialog().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form2 will need a reference to Form1

```
form_Form2 f = new form_Form2();
f.OtherForm = this;
this.Hide();
f.Show();
```

You will have to add `OtherForm` property. Then later in Form 2

```
OtherForm.Show();
```

Comment: what do you mean by add OtherForm property?

Comment: You have to add a property to `form_Form2` to store the reference to Form1. I called this `OtherForm`. You will have to add this in `form_Form2` class as `public Form OtherForm {get; set;}`to run the above code.